# Connect two different dataframes into one

Tags: r, dataframe

I have two different dataframes and they haven't any common column to connect them. Is there any way to create a new dataframe from two different dataframes without any common column? The one of dataframes contains days values.

Example of first dataframe:

```
 day
 2000-01-01 00:00:00
 2000-01-01 00:01:00
 2000-01-01 00:02:00
```

Example of the second data frame:

```
 price
  1
  2
  3
```

The results of new data frame:

```
     day              price
 2000-01-01 00:00:00    1
 2000-01-01 00:01:00    2
 2000-01-01 00:02:00    3
```

Comment: I've no idea what days values mean. Please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Comment: @csgillespie I made an update with example of data format

Comment: Why doesn't cbind of the two columns work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about `data.frame`? - :

```
 data.frame(day,price)
```

Here's an example. Two input data frames:

```
> a
    x y
1   1 a
2   2 b
3   3 c
4   4 d
5   5 e
6   6 f
7   7 g
8   8 h
9   9 i
10 10 j
> b
    v     w
1  14 FALSE
2   5  TRUE
3   8  TRUE
4   4  TRUE
5  17 FALSE
6   5  TRUE
7  15 FALSE
8  11 FALSE
9  15 FALSE
10  9  TRUE
```

And here's how `data.frame` works:

```
> data.frame(a,b)
    x y  v     w
1   1 a 14 FALSE
2   2 b  5  TRUE
3   3 c  8  TRUE
4   4 d  4  TRUE
5   5 e 17 FALSE
6   6 f  5  TRUE
7   7 g 15 FALSE
8   8 h 11 FALSE
9   9 i 15 FALSE
10 10 j  9  TRUE
```

Neat.

Answer (score 1):

What about `cbind`?

```
dd1 = data.frame(x1 = runif(10), y1=runif(10))
dd2 = data.frame(x2 = runif(10), y2=runif(10))
```

So

```
dd = cbind(dd1, dd2)
```

Comment: Where do you mention this in your question?

Answer (score 0):

Here's the `data.table` approach, which may be useful for larger `data.frame`s:

```
library(data.table)
### if converting from data.frame:
df1 <- data.frame(a=c(1,2,3))
dt1 <- data.table(df1)
### or more simply:
dt1 <- data.table(a=c(1,2,3))
dt2 <- data.table(b=c(4,5,6))
dt3 <- data.table(dt1,dt2)
dt3
```

gives:

```
   a b
1: 1 4
2: 2 5
3: 3 6
```